# Not greedy quantification in regular expression

Tags: c#, regex

I have a string like `m(2,n(3))`.

I need to retrieve all matches (calls) with regex:

- `m(2,n(3))`
- `n(3)`

My variant of regex -

```
(m|n\((.*?)\))
```

It doesn't work.

Comment: You need to use recursion if you want it to treat the nested call as a unit.

Comment: See http://www.regular-expressions.info/recurse.html

Comment: This is equivalent to the balanced parenthesis language and is *context-free*. You cannot ever achieve this using a simple regex. The better option here would be to use a stack and parse left to right. I'd love to give pseudo code if you're interested.

Comment: What language are you using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make use of balanced constructs in .NET regex. Together with a positive look-ahead we can match nested expressions like this:

```
(?=(\b\w+\b\((?>[^()]+|\((?<n>)|\)(?<-n>))*(?(n)(?!))\)))
```

The values are stored in Group 1.

See [demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=(%3f%3d(%5cb%5cw%2b%5cb%5c((%3f%3e%5b%5e()%5d%2b%7c%5c((%3f%3cn%3e)%7c%5c)(%3f%3c-n%3e))*(%3f(n)(%3f!))%5c)))&i=m(2%2cn(3))%2c+call(param%2c3)) (go to *Table* tab to see the actual results).

```
var rx = new Regex(@"(?=(\b\w+\b\((?>[^()]+|\((?<n>)|\)(?<-n>))*(?(n)(?!))\)))");
var str = "m(2,n(3)), call(param,3)";
var matches = rx.Matches(str).OfType<Match>().Select(p => p.Groups[1].Value).ToList();
```

[image]

Comment: Great (bit hard to understand for me), but contains a issue - when string contains a multi char name, for example "call(param,3)", it gives strange result.

Comment: I have updated the answer. In short, `\b\w+\b` is matching the operator before parentheses, and `\((?>[^()]+|\((?<n>)|\)(?<-n>))*(?(n)(?!))\)` matches matching opening and closing round brackets. These subpatterns are enclosed into a positive look-ahead to allow overlapping matches.